# How to scrape the table data from canvas in Angular Application

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I am facing an issue with scraping the table data from the Canvas element . Its a Tableau Application (Web) . I want to scrape the details of the tables . How can i proceed with that . Its an Angular Application .

Comment: Post what you have so far and any error messages. Off the info you have posted above, BeautifulSoup won't help. You will need something like Selenium that loads the js.

Comment: I am checking the feasibility of scraping the data from canvas .

Comment: How to do with selenium

Comment: I suggest you read up on the Selenium docs. They are pretty good and should get you going on your scraping project.

Comment: With selenium , i am not able to get the dom of canvas elements .